# Difference between lexical vs canonical representation in XSD spec

Tags: xml, xsd, specifications, xsd-validation

I was referencing the [XSD spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal) today looking up the definition of a decimal type. In it, I found two different conflicting definitions of the datatype, a lexical definition and a canonical definition quoted below:

> *3.2.3.1 Lexical representation*
>
> **decimal** has a lexical representation consisting of a finite-length
>   sequence of decimal digits (#x30-#x39) separated by a period as a
>   decimal indicator. An optional leading sign is allowed. If the sign is
>   omitted, "+" is assumed. Leading and trailing zeroes are optional.
>   **If the fractional part is zero, the period and following zero(es) can be omitted.** For example: -1.23, 12678967.543233, +100000.00,
>   210.
>
> *3.2.3.2 Canonical representation*
>
> The canonical representation for **decimal** is defined by prohibiting
>   certain options from the Lexical representation (§3.2.3.1).
>   Specifically, the preceding optional "+" sign is prohibited. **The
>   decimal point is required.** Leading and trailing zeroes are
>   prohibited subject to the following: there must be at least one digit
>   to the right and to the left of the decimal point which may be a zero.

In summary, the lexical representation permits the absence of a decimal point and trailing zeros if the fractional part of the decimal is zero, whereas the canonical representation explicitly states the decimal is required.

Which of these definitions is "correct"? My application is sending lexical representation and a consuming application is expecting canonical representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Validity in XSD is defined against the lexical representation, not the canonical representation, so your application is perfectly within its right according to any contract given strictly by an XSD calling for a `xs:decimal` to exclude the decimal point in the absence of a fractional part.

The canonical representation isn't used within XSD but offers a standard way to serialize datatypes to other W3C recommendations such as XPath/XQuery.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. A coding friend also found this article which really helped me understand that this was less of an xml spec question and actually a question generic to any data type definition in any language or specification (I found the images especially illustrative of the concept): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/srivastava-datatypes-087961.html